# is this right code for sound recognition in visual basic

Tags: vb.net, audio

I want to insure this code for getting the audio level value when vb receive sound from user ,

I have some warning when I run this code and when I call the function in another class .

getting the audio level value of sound recognition code :

```
Imports System.Speech
Imports System.Speech.Recognition
Imports AxShockwaveFlashObjects.AxShockwaveFlash
Imports AxShockwaveFlashObjects

Public Class sound1
Private recognizer As New SpeechRecognitionEngine()

Dim value As Boolean

Sub recognizer_AudioLevelUpdated(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As AudioLevelUpdatedEventArgs)

    recognizer = New SpeechRecognitionEngine
    recognizer.LoadGrammar(New Grammar(New GrammarBuilder("just nothing")))
    ' the warning at the above line " InvalidOperationException Was unhandled - The language for the grammar does not match the language of the speech recognizer."  
    AddHandler recognizer.AudioLevelUpdated, AddressOf recognizer_AudioLevelUpdated
    recognizer.SetInputToDefaultAudioDevice()
    recognizer.RecognizeAsync(RecognizeMode.Multiple)
    value = e.AudioLevel
    Do While value > 70
        'Console.WriteLine(value)
        MessageBox.Show(value)
     Loop
     End Sub
     End Class
```

calling audio level function :

```
Imports System.Speech.Recognition
Imports System.Speech.Recognition.GrammarBuilder
Imports AxShockwaveFlashObjects.AxShockwaveFlash
Imports AxShockwaveFlashObjects

Public Class flashWithSound
Dim s As New sound1
Dim sender As Object
Dim e As AudioLevelUpdatedEventArgs


Private Sub Form2_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load


End Sub

Private Sub AxShockwaveFlash1_Enter(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles AxShockwaveFlash1.Enter

End Sub

Private Sub Button3_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
    s.recognizer_AudioLevelUpdated(sender, e)
' the warning at the above line "InvalidCastException Was unhandled - couldn't convert object from type 'System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs' to type 'System.Speech.Recognition.AudioLevelUpdatedEventArgs'."
End Sub

End Class
```

so how I can fix these warning please ,,

Comment: how in the world can anyone help if all they know is there is "some warning"?  what is the message and where does it appear?

Comment: I mention that in codes as a comment , focus in the codes!

Answer (score 1):

The event arguments for `System.Speech.Recognition.AudioLevelUpdatedEventArgs` are different to `System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs`. You can't have the button click event handling the `AudioLevelEvent` like this.
Just write a separate sub to handle the event and you should be good to go.

Comment: you mean i have to change the tool instead of button or change the event of button ??

Comment: and what about the Previous warning in first code which is about grammar ? and thank you so much